# C# - Textbox Newline Problems

Tags: c#

I have a textbox, and I'm trying to print to it with the following line of code:

```
logfiletextbox.Text = logfiletextbox.Text + "\n\n\n\n\n" + o + " copied to " + folderlabel2.Text;
```

Where folderlabel 2 is obviously a textbox. The first thing I've put in is the same textbox, so that no text is erased. The excessive new lines have proven my problem, because there are no new lines in the textbox (yes, set to multiline). The "o" is of type FileInfo in a FileInfo array.

Why won't these newlines show up in the text box?

Comment: You need to use CRLF pairs when inserting into a textbox \r\n.

Comment: In case of UWP the TextBox has to be set explicitly to a mode were it accepts multiple lines  `AcceptsReturn="True"` or `TextWrapping="Wrap"` it doesn't care about "\r\n" vs "\n".

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Use "\r\n" instead of "\n". Windows text boxes need CRLF as line terminators, not just LF.

Potentially you *could* use `Environment.NewLine` instead - but I don't know what Mono TextBoxes do in terms of working with "\n" (which is what `Environment.NewLine` would be on a Linux box). If it starts putting extra stuff at the end if you use "\r\n" then that will break plenty of existing apps - but if it *requires* "\r\n" that would break apps which use `Environment.NewLine`.

`Environment.NewLine` is meant to be the default new line for the whole platform you're running on - but what if you're using a widget toolkit which does one thing, but text files typically do something else? Frankly it's a bit of a mess. It would be nice if there were a separate `TextBox.NewLine` property which different implementations could handle appropriately.

Comment: Or even better, use `Environment.NewLine`.

Comment: A TextBox-specific NewLine property would be nice.  I wonder if it would make sense to allow form applications to set that property to a specified value.  I.e. if you're using a TextBox to display text for read/write to a database, web service, or anything where the newline convention is not actually tied to your currently executing platform, then it might make sense to allow the developer to set the TextBox's newline string to match the source/destination text.

Answer (score 6):

I believe TextBoxes want an `Environment.NewLine` (which should be "\r\n")

Note that it must be the carriage return (\r) followed by the new line (\n).  If you reverse the order, it won't work.

Answer (score 2):

A TextBox control expects a Carriage Return before your Line Feeds (0x0D 0x0A).  Use `"\r\n"` or `System.Environment.Newline`.

Answer (score 2):

in stead of using \n we can use

**Environment.NewLine**

i hope it will help

Answer (score 0):

This is how i created append and new line for display
txtitems.Text = txtitems.Text + Environment.NewLine + dr[0].ToString() +" "+dr[1].ToString();

Answer (score 0):

Anyone that is using VB.net, be on the lookout for **vbCr**

Here is an example:

return "My name is" & vbCr & "John" & vbCr & "Doe"