# c# Using Substring and Regular Expressions to edit a large string

Tags: c#, regex, foreach, substring

The string, when displayed looks like: value1, value2, value3, value4, value5 etc..

What I want the string to do once I display it is (removing spaces and commas, i assume I can use index + 2 or something to get past the comma):

value1

value2

etc...

```
lastKnownIndexPos = 0;

foreach (System.Text.RegularExpressions.Match m in System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Matches(unformatedList, ",?")) //Currently is ',' can I use ', '?
{
    list += unformatedList.Substring(lastKnownIndexPos, m.Index - 1) + "\n\n"; //-1 to grab just the first value.

    lastIndex = m.Index + 2; //to skip the comma and the space to get to the first letter of the next word.

    //lastIndex++; //used this to count how many times it was found, maxed at 17 (have over 100):(
}

//MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(lastIndex)); //used to display total times each was found.

MessageBox.Show(list);
```

At the moment the message box does not show any text, but using the lastIndex I get a value of 17 so I know it works for part of it :P

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's easy (I'm `using System.Linq` here):

```
var formatted = string.Join("\n\n", unformatedList.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim()));
MessageBox.Show(formatted);
```

An alternative approach, as swannee pointed out, would be the following:

```
var formatted = Regex.Replace(unformatedList, @"\s*,\s*", "\n\n").Trim();
```

**Edit:**
To make the above examples work regardless of how you use the result string, you should use `Environment.NewLine` instead of `"\n"`.

Comment: Well that was surprisingly easy :P (got to wait 5 minutes to give you the solve :P). It works and now the data flows off the page :P I think I will have to use another form rather than a message box (from memory I don't think you can resize them or give them a vertical scrollbar)

Comment: This worked perfectly in messagebox, now that I am using a form, and I try to call: supportedListTxtBx.Text = formatted;

The data is displayed but all in a line again (i.e. value1value2). So the ", " is gone but the \n\n wasn't added :(

Comment: nevermind fixed it with: var formatted = string.Join("\r\n", unformatedList.Split(',').Select(x => x.Trim())); http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3207683/c-sharp-textbox-newline-problems

Answer (score 2):

One way is to simply replace the ", " with a newline.

```
MessageBox.Show( unformatedList.Replace(", ", "\n") );
```

Answer (score 2):

Or heck, why not just use string.Replace?

```
var formatted = unformattedList.Replace(", ", "\n\n");
```

Comment: This was my first solution as well, but I then went for the slightly more complex approach as I don't know where the data comes from and therefore cannot be sure if it's guaranteed that there's exactly one space after each comma ;)

Comment: Sure Tobias, but you can use the similar RegEx.Replace in that case with regular expression pattern ",\s+"

Comment: Sure, but a habit of mine is not to use regexes unless it dramatically reduces my effort, because they tend to be inefficient both in memory and runtime.

Comment: Yeah agree Tobias, my only issue with the linq syntax is it doesn't reveal it's intention (not that it's that complex), but it could easily be wrapped into it's own "Replace" extension method for easier reading.