# UWP TextBox.SelectedText changes \r\n to \r

Tags: c#, textbox, uwp

I need to get the characters that **preceed a TextBox's `SelectedText`**, but I can't get the SelectionStart to match up with the TextBoxes' Text properties, apparently because TextBox's SelectedText scrubs `\n` values.

I have a Windows 10 UWP application. I've added two TextBoxes and one Button, as represented by the XAML below:

```
<StackPanel>
    <Rectangle Height="40"></Rectangle><!-- quicker than turning off debug numbers -->
    <TextBox Height="300" Name="textBox" AcceptsReturn="True" />
    <Button Click="Button_Click" Content="Selection" ></Button>
    <TextBox Height="100" Name="textBox2" AcceptsReturn="True" />
</StackPanel>
```

I've initialized the Page by putting some text into the first TextBox.

```
    public MainPage()
    {
        this.InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Page_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
            this.textBox.Text = @"Call me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--having little
or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I
thought I would sail about a little and see the watery part of the world. It is
a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever
I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly
November in my soul; whenever I find myself involuntarily pausing before coffin
warehouses, and bringing up the rear of every funeral I meet; and especially
whenever my hypos get such an upper hand of me, that it requires a strong moral
principle to prevent me from deliberately stepping into the street, and
methodically knocking people's hats off--then, I account it high time to get to
sea as soon as I can.";
    }
```

I would've expected something like the following would get what's selected (again, I don't need SelectedText; I need the previous characters, but I'm grabbing what's selected here to make things easier to follow):

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox.Text.Substring(textBox.SelectionStart,
            20 < textBox.SelectionLength ? 20 : textBox.SelectionLength);
    }
```

That doesn't. It strangely seems to get `SelectionStart` based on a value for `textBox.Text` that doesn't include `\n`. Here's what I mean...

If I highlight the first two lines...

> Call me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--having little
>   or no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I

... things work, and I get back what I'd expect ("Call me Ishmael. Som"). But with each drop down a line, I get one more character than I'd expect. So lines 2 & 3 give a newline first (`\n` extra):

[image]

If we jump ahead to lines 4 and 5 (so we're skipping three lines), I get three characters back before the selection.

That is, selecting this...

> a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever
>   I find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly

... gives this...

> s\r\n
>   a way I have of d

[image: extra characters]

(Note: I've highlighted what *was* selected manually here, just to help visualize what's going on.)

If I check `SelectedText`, every newline is reduced to a `\r`, so this almost makes sense, except that `textBox.Text` still has platform appropriate `\r\n`'s instead!

That is, if I put a breakpoint in the `Button_Click` event, and check `textBox.SelectedText`, I get...

```
"a way I have of driving off the spleen and regulating the circulation. Whenever\rI find myself growing grim about the mouth; whenever it is a damp, drizzly\r"
```

See the `\r` only? Yet `textBox.Text` gives...

```
"Call me Ishmael. Some years ago--never mind how long precisely--having little\r\nor no money in my purse, and nothing particular to interest me on shore, I\r\n[...]"
```

If I want to get what I'd expect, I can do something silly like...

```
    public static string NormalizeNewlineToCarriageReturn(this string str)
    {
        str = str.Replace("\r\n", "\r");
        str = str.Replace("\n", "\r");
        return str;
    }
```

And then...

```
    private void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        textBox2.Text = textBox.Text.NormalizeNewlineToCarriageReturn().Substring(textBox.SelectionStart,
            20 < textBox.SelectionLength ? 20 : textBox.SelectionLength);
    }
```

But that's *crazy*. And if TextBox ever starts working like I'd expect, that breaks.

What's going on? I mean, I see explanations (like [this from Mr. Skeet](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3207702/1028230)) that seem to shortcircuit to "You need to use `NewLine`" to explain missing `\n`'s in TextBoxes, but in UWP, at least, I think it's more complicated than that.

Comment: Did you find any solution to this problem? I'm also stuck.

Comment: @AnupSharma I need to properly document and prep the code, but I've been using the [kludges I put on github here](https://github.com/ruffin--/UWPBox), emphasis on the [`KludgeItUp` variable here](https://github.com/ruffin--/UWPBox/blob/master/UWPBox/org/rufwork/UI/widgets/UWPBox.cs#L146). It's a bit ugly. If you can think of a better way, give me a pull! It drives me crazy. I did [post a bug to the .NET team](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/2967753), but they said, "*We have determined that this issue belongs to the Windows Platform team*", which was disappointing.

Comment: I'm using a hack to solve the problem. In back-end I'm using regex to calculate number of new line and subtracting it to get proper selection index.

Comment: @AnupSharma Yeah, same deal in that [TextBox extension, above.](https://github.com/ruffin--/UWPBox). Watch out for the condition where the bug would have the string you're using to determine the number of newlines ends in `"\r"`, b/c it'll potentially off-by-one you. I have parallel properties for `SelectionStart` and `SelectedText` with `2_ForText` appended to their names that *will* work as expected for `this.Text`. In each, I sniff behavior when calculating them to see if the TextBox has fixed itself, b/c otherwise I'd end up with that hack screwing up TextBox once they do fix it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip. I'm sure they are not going to fix it though.

Comment: Have the same issue. Ended up using your _NormalizeNewlineToCarriageReturn_ "crazy" approach.