# UWP TextBox puts \r only - how to set LineBreak

Tags: c#, xaml, textbox, uwp

I fill a TextBox with multiple lines from clipboard, which contains `\r\n` as linebreak (so same as in `Environment.NewLine`. After I make a change and want to get the text, I get only `\r` as linebreaks back. Is there any way to change this?

Comment: Maybe setting the [`AcceptsReturn`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.textbox#Windows_UI_Xaml_Controls_TextBox_AcceptsReturn) property to `true` could help.

Comment: I did already. This made the `TextBox` accepting multiline texts at all.

Comment: str.Replace("\r","\r\n")

Comment: This will cause a lot of checkings for changed data... but well. Thank you ;)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I find the UWPBox can help you.

UWPBox: https://github.com/ruffin--/UWPBox

As the author say:

Let me emphasize that first one. Even if Environment.NewLine is \r\n, and you have \r\n all over myTextBox.Text, if you check myTextBox.SelectedText, at least in Windows 10 for PCs, all newlines will be turned into \r!!! This makes for really wacky integrations of changes to SelectedText back into the context of Text. See the [StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35138047/textbox-text-substringtextbox-selectionstart-doesnt-work-because-selectedtext) question for a specific example.

Comment: Thank you. A bit sad by the original TextBox.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to always have `\r\n` for line breaks, no matter if `TextBox.Text` gives you `\r` or `\n` (like on Android/iOS in Uno Platform), do the following.

In your XAML file, add the converter namespace to the top-level element:

```
xmlns:converters="using:MyConverters"
```

Add the converter as a static resource to your XAML file:

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:LineEndingsConverter x:Key="LineEndingsConverter" />
</Page.Resources>
```

Bind the `TextBox.Text` property to a property in your ViewModel, and use the `LineEndingsConverter` to convert line endings:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding SomeText, Converter={StaticResource LineEndingsConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}" />
```

```
#nullable enable
using System;
using Windows.UI.Xaml.Data;

namespace MyConverters
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Because TextBox returns text with '\r' for line breaks on UWP and '\n' on Xamarin instead of '\r\n', this converts them to '\r\n'
    /// </summary>
    public class LineEndingsConverter : IValueConverter
    {
        public object? Convert(object? value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is string input)
            {
                return MyHelpers.LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);
            }
            return value;
        }

        public object? ConvertBack(object? value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
        {
            if (value is string input)
            {
                return MyHelpers.LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);
            }
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

## Implementation

```
#nullable enable
using System.Text;

namespace MyHelpers
{
    public static class LineEndingsConverter
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Converts all "\r" and "\n" line breaks in a string to "\r\n", leaving existing "\r\n" line breaks unchanged.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="input">The input string to convert line breaks for.</param>
        /// <returns>The input string with all "\r" and "\n" line breaks converted to "\r\n".</returns>
        public static string? ConvertLineEndings(in string? input)
        {
            if (input is null or "")
            {
                return input;
            }

            var sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
            bool previousWasCarriageReturn = false;

            foreach (char c in input)
            {
                if (c == '\r')
                {
                    if (previousWasCarriageReturn)
                    {
                        sb.Append(c);
                        previousWasCarriageReturn = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        previousWasCarriageReturn = true;
                    }
                }
                else if (c == '\n')
                {
                    if (previousWasCarriageReturn)
                    {
                        sb.Append("\r\n");
                        previousWasCarriageReturn = false;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        sb.Append("\r\n");
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    if (previousWasCarriageReturn)
                    {
                        sb.Append("\r\n");
                        previousWasCarriageReturn = false;
                    }
                    sb.Append(c);
                }
            }

            if (previousWasCarriageReturn)
            {
                sb.Append("\r\n");
            }

            return sb.ToString();
        }
    }
}
```

## Tests:

```
#nullable enable
using MyHelpers;
using FluentAssertions;
using Xunit;

namespace MyHelpers.Tests
{
    public class LineEndingsConverterFixture
    {
        [Fact]
        public void Given_NullInput_When_ConvertingLineEndings_Then_ReturnsNull()
        {
            // Given
            string? input = null;

            // When
            var output = LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);

            // Then
            output.Should().BeNull();
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given_EmptyInput_When_ConvertingLineEndings_Then_ReturnsEmptyString()
        {
            // Given
            string? input = "";

            // When
            var output = LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);

            // Then
            output.Should().Be("");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given_InputWithOnlyCarriageReturn_When_ConvertingLineEndings_Then_ReturnsInputWithCarriageReturnAndLineFeed()
        {
            // Given
            string? input = "Hello\rWorld\r";

            // When
            var output = LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);

            // Then
            output.Should().Be("Hello\r\nWorld\r\n");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given_InputWithOnlyNewline_When_ConvertingLineEndings_Then_ReturnsInputWithCarriageReturnAndLineFeed()
        {
            // Given
            string? input = "Hello\nWorld\n";

            // When
            var output = LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);

            // Then
            output.Should().Be("Hello\r\nWorld\r\n");
        }

        [Fact]
        public void Given_InputWithMixedLineBreaks_When_ConvertingLineEndings_Then_ReturnsInputWithCarriageReturnAndLineFeed()
        {
            // Given
            string? input = "Hello\r\nWorld\n";

            // When
            var output = LineEndingsConverter.ConvertLineEndings(input);

            // Then
            output.Should().Be("Hello\r\nWorld\r\n");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to read lines from TextBox in an UWP (CS) Windows 10 App, go with **"\r"** only,

```
 string[] InputStringArray= InputTextBox.Text.Split("\r");
```

You can use Join to insert **"\r\n"**

```
string result = string.Join("\r\n", InputStringArray);
```